# Repeat row vector as matrix with different offsets in each row

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I want to repeat a row vector to create a matrix, in which every row is a slightly modified version of the original vector.

For example, if I have a vector `v = [10 20 30 40 50]`, I want every row of my matrix to be that vector, but with a random number added to every element of the vector to add some fluctuations.

My matrix should look like this:

```
M = [10+a 20+a 30+a 40+a 50+a; 
     10+b 20+b 30+b 40+b 50+b; 
     ... ]
```

Where `a`, `b`, ... are random numbers between 0 and 2, for an arbitrary number of matrix rows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a MATLAB version earlier than 2016b (when implicit expansion was introduced, as demonstrated in Daan's answer) then you should use `bsxfun`.

```
v = [10 20 30 40 50]; % initial row vector
offsets = rand(3,1);  % random values, add one per row (this should be a column vector)

output = bsxfun(@plus,offsets,v);
```

Result:

```
>> output =
   10.643   20.643   30.643   40.643   50.643
   10.704   20.704   30.704   40.704   50.704
   10.393   20.393   30.393   40.393   50.393
```

---

This can be more easily understood with less random inputs!

```
v = [10 20 30 40 50];
offsets = [1; 2; 3];

output = bsxfun(@plus,offsets,v);
>> output =
   11   21   31   41   51
   12   22   32   42   52
   13   23   33   43   53
```

---

Side note: to get an `nx1` vector of random numbers between 0 and 2, use

```
offsets = rand(n,1)*2
```

Comment: Yes that was helpful, thanks a lot!
A tiny edit for anyone else reading this:
M needs to be defined first to be the matrix consisting of v in each row. Simply add M = v(ones(3,1),:); between offsets and output.

Comment: Oops that was a copy and paste typo on my part! I've changed the `M`s to `v` which should now work :)

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, you can add a column vector to a matrix. This will add the vector elements to each of the row values accordingly.

Example:

```
>> M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> v = [1; 2; 3];
>> v + M

ans =

     2     3     4
     6     7     8
    10    11    12
```

Note that in your case `v` is a row vector, so you should transpose it first (using `v.'`).

As [Sardar Usama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650139/repeat-row-vector-as-matrix-with-different-offsets-in-each-row/45650198#comment78258957_45650198) and [Wolfie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45656143/5207081) note, this method of adding is only possible since MATLAB version R2016b, for earlier versions you will need to use [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
>> % instead of `v + M`
>> bsxfun(@plus, v, M)

ans =

     2     4     6
     5     7     9
     8    10    12
```

Comment: [`'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) is not transpose. [`.'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) is. Implicit expansion is introduced in R2016b. Use `bsxfun` for earlier versions. i.e `bsxfun(@plus,v.',M)`

Comment: Hi Daan,
your answer doesn't work out for me. If I use your code, I get an error:
Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in test (line 3)
v + M

Comment: @Surstroemmingpirat Possibly your version does not support this. Try to initialize `v` by `v = repmat([1, 2, 3].', 1, size(M, 1))` to get `v` to the same dimensions as `M`. Does that work for you?

Comment: `bsxfun(@plus, v.', M)` is the equivalent of `v.' + M`, not `v+M`.   (I used `v.'` in my comment since the OP has `v` as a row vector, not a column vector)